# Running a Server / Client from a different class in JAVA

Tags: java

I have two classes, Server and Client, and I want to exchange int arrays between both for a game. What I am thinking of doing is running the Server and Client from a different class Game where all my interface / algorithms are implemented. So I just don't know how to run Server and Client from my actionListeners.

Code for Server:

```
public class Serveur{
    static int [] pos;

    public static int[] getData(Socket s){
        try{
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();  
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);  
            pos = (int[])ois.readObject();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("No Class");
        }
            return pos;
    }

    public static void main(String[] zero){


        try{    
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3000);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            getData(s);
            for(int i=0; i<pos.length; i++)
                System.out.println(pos[i]);
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Code for Client:

```
public class Client {



    /**
     *Method sending arrays to the Server
     */
    public static void sendData(Socket s, int[] pos) throws IOException{
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();  
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);  
            oos.writeObject(pos); 
        }

    public static void main(String[] zero){


        Socket socket;
        try {
            int [] pos = {1,2};
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),3000);
            sendData(socket, pos);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

It's just a first test and I'm quite new to Sockets. When i run this in Terminal, I go: 
java Serveur
and in another one:
java Client

Then my Server prints 1 2.

So how do I run the Server and Client from another class? The idea is to have an actionListener for starting the game which will launch Server and when someone else tries to connect it creates a Client which puts both in connection. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

I hope I'm precise enough. Thank you

Comment: If you know how to use threads/runnables, you can make two threads, each of which just calls either `Client.main(new String[]())` or `Serveur.main(new String[]())`.  If you're not familiar with that, I'd recommend waiting and just doing two terminals for now.

Comment: Thank for that, I managed it out using Runnable, works fine now :)